# Microsoft Excel 2010: Copying multiple cell entries and placing them in a single column or row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

```
30  42  50  78  99  119
47  50  81      120
47  56          
    57          
    60          
    61          
    62          
    62          
    64          
    67
```

I have data in Excel like this and I just want all of those cell entries to be in a single row or column i.e. 30 42 47 47 50 56 .... How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think there is a paste option for that but you can select each row/column independently, then hover over the side till you see the move icon (4 arrows up, down, left, right) then move them on top or copy each row/column independently then paste transposed.

Comment: You can write a macro for this - 1. Find the number of rows filled with data in the first column 2. copy the next column data in (last cell+1) in column 1 3. Repeat until the last column is finished. For step 1 macros are readily available in superuser itself

Answer (score 0):

if u copy a row then paste it with transpose to a column that should do it
just repeat till all r in the same column - blank cells will be copied also so u will have to delete the rows the blanks r in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have loads and loads of this to do, or you're doing it frequently, then you might be best off with a macro.  A macro can make use of code like:

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
```

which will select A1, all the way down until the bottom of text.  And then do something with a loop across all columns, pasting each time into the cell one below the bottom of column A, which you can get to with this.

```
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).Select
```

But you'd need someone to spend the time to write the macro properly.

Alternatively, if you've only got small numbers of these to do, then it might just be quicker to do it manually.

Quickest way I can think of is just to

- click in the top of column B
- Crtl-Shift-DownArrow to select all the data in the column
- Ctrl-C to copy
- Click in cell A1
- Ctrl-DownArrow, then DownArrow on its own once, to get to the first blank cell in column A
- Ctrl-V to paste
- Repeat for each column C onwards.  Wouldn't take that long for only a dozen columns.

The macro would basically do the same as that, it'd just do it a lot quicker than a human ;-)